# Storing path from A*, using operator::new with boost::multi_array

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use dynamic memory allocation for the first time. I want to allocate memory for a 2 dim dynamic array, to store paths from an A* function. I think the array for the job is boost::multi_array.

Problem I seem to be able to allocate the memory but i can't change or access any of the elements.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "boost/multi_array.hpp"

typedef boost::multi_array<int, 2> array_type;

int main()
{
    array_type *A = new array_type;

    A->resize( boost::extents[2][2] );

    A[1][1] = 2;

    std::cout << A[1][1] << std::endl;

    delete A;

    return 0;
}
```

**Compiler says**:

```
C:\Coding\Code Projects\C++\Source Files\Console\main-read.cpp|14|error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::cout << boost::multi_array_ref<T, NumDims>::operator[](boost::multi_array_ref<T, NumDims>::index) [with T = int; unsigned int NumDims = 2u; boost::multi_array_ref<T, NumDims>::reference = boost::detail::multi_array::sub_array<int, 1u>; boost::multi_array_ref<T, NumDims>::index = int](1)'|.
```

I have tried so over ways of declaring A, but can't seem to find a solution. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution works for me. Sorry for the confusion before.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "boost/multi_array.hpp"

typedef boost::multi_array<int, 2> array_type;

int main()
{
    array_type *A = new array_type(boost::extents[2][2]);
    (*A)[1][1] = 2;
    std::cout << (*A)[1][1] << std::endl;
    delete A;
    return 0;
}
```